# excel showing count instead of sum

Tags: microsoft-excel

A colleague of mine has an exel file, on one sheet on a few columns when you select multiple cells it shows the sum, but the problem is that on other column it only shows count and not sum.

Any idea why?

Comment: PS: columns have number formatting

Comment: When you say "shows", do you mean the 'hint' in the status bar bottom-right?

Comment: "columns have number formatting" - that doesn't mean all those data are actually numbers, probably at least part of them are text. Have a look e.g. here: https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-isnumber-function

Comment: just checked and it looks like the data in the cell is not a number

Comment: please enter your comment as an answer, so I can accept it

Answer (score 1):

The data (atleast in that column) has been copied from a source which is delimited. Hence that column is delimited text. To rectify, select the whole column at the top and then on the ribbon, click on Data-> Text to column and then select delimited (not fixed width) in the appearing window, click next, select tab (normally default), select next and then finish.

It will convert the data to numbers.